# Retrieving multiple query parameters from inbound gateway

Tags: http, spring-integration

I have a configuration that should service query parameters and return a response. Here is my configuration. Unfortunately, the Service Activator bean cannot be created by Spring.

```
<int-http:inbound-gateway request-channel="inChannel"
        reply-channel="outChannel" supported-methods="GET" 
        path="/ticket">

        <int-http:request-mapping consumes="text/plain" params="param1,param2,param3"
            produces="text/plain" />
</int-http:inbound-gateway>

<int:service-activator ref="ticketIssuingService" method="processTicket"
        input-channel="inChannel" output-channel="outChannel"/>
```

---

```
@MessageEndpoint
public class TicketIssuingService {



    public String processTicket(??? payload){
        System.out.println("Query Paramter String is "+payload);
        return null;
    }
}
```

http://localhost:8080/job/ticket?param1=type&param2=linkstate&param3=duration

How can I retrieve the parameters so that I can handoff to the processTicket method? Spring complains that no eligible methods were found. What should the arguments be for the method processTicket? Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `GET` method without `payload-expression` the `payload` of the `Message<?>` for your `inChannel` is exactly this object:

```
MultiValueMap<String, String> requestParams = this.convertParameterMap(servletRequest.getParameterMap());

...

        if (payload == null) {
            if (requestBody != null) {
                payload = requestBody;
            }
            else {
                payload = requestParams;
            }
        }
```

So, that should be an answer for your question about the `payload` type in the `processTicket` service method.

Pay attention, please, that you can customize that `payload` via `payload-expression` and using some built-in SpEL `EvaluationContext` [variables](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/http.html#_uri_template_variables_and_expressions) like:

```
#requestParams - the MultiValueMap from the ServletRequest parameterMap.
#pathVariables - the Map from URI Template placeholders and their values;
#matrixVariables - the Map of MultiValueMap according to Spring MVC Specification. Note, #matrixVariables require Spring MVC 3.2 or higher;
#requestAttributes - the org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestAttributes associated with the current Request;
#requestHeaders - the org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders object from the current Request;
#cookies - the Map<String, Cookie> of javax.servlet.http.Cookie s from the current Request.
```

Some sample is like this to get the `queryString`:

```
payload-expression="T(org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder).requestAttributes.request.queryString"
```